# Multi selection bootstrap insert in database Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to create multi selection bootstrap output to save in database but I'm getting an array in my controller like `["6","7"]`. How I can save this?

There is 2 selection that means 2 row must created.

The query I was trying:

```php
$table = Pool_user::updateOrInsert(['pool_id' => [$string1], 'user_id' => $request['id']]);
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By responding directly to your question, you need to create an array of arrays with the values you want to enter.

Something like this:

```php
$array = [];
foreach($request['pool_ids'] as $pool_id){ //$request['pool_ids'] -> ["6","7"]
   array_push($array, [
      'pool_id' => $pool_id,
      'user_id' => $request['id']
   ]);
}

$table = Pool_user::insert($array);
```

However, considering that `Pool_user` is a Pivot table of a Many to Many relationship, there is a much better method of doing this.
Let's say in User Model, have a relationship called `polls()`.

You can simply ask the Eloquent to synchronize the relationships:

```php
$user = User::find($request['id']);
$user->polls()->sync($request['pool_ids']); //$request['pool_ids'] -> ["6","7"]
```

Hope this helps